# Creating a list of missing files after reading paths from another list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of file paths `listt`:

```
['/data0/river_routes.nc',
 '/dat/rho0_profile.nc',...]
```

I want to check if they exist, and if not - create a list `list1` with just the paths of the missing files.

I can create `list1` full of `True/False` using:

```py
import os,time
list1 = []
for file in listt:
    list1.append(os.path.isfile(file))
```

But I'm not sure how to create a list of the missing paths in the most efficient way

Comment: `list1 = [file for file in listt if not os.path.isfile(file)]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the path not the `bool` that `isfile` returns.

```
from os.path import isfile

paths = ['/data0/river_routes.nc', '/dat/rho0_profile.nc',...]

missing_paths = []
for path in paths:
    if not isfile(path):
        missing_paths.append(path)
```

This can also be done using a list comprehension:

```
missing_paths = [path for path in paths if not isfile(path)]
```

Or you can use `itertools.filterfalse`:

```
from itertools import filterfalse as ffilter
missing_paths = list(filter(ispath, paths))
```

Comment: Thank you! One question, is this returning the missing ones or the existing ones?

Comment: The missing ones. I edited with more appropriate variable names. Best to use good naming conventions

Comment: @Jab good naming is important indeed, but correct code even more so - your current snippets list existing files, not missing ones xD

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```py
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    paths = ['/data0/river_routes.nc',
             '/dat/rho0_profile.nc']
    missing = []
    for item in paths:
        p = Path(item)
        if not p.exists():
            missing.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehension

```
import os

not_exists = [f for f in list1 if not os.path.exists(f)]
```

where list1 is list with paths

Comment: this is usually known as "list comprehension"

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract a set of found from all:

```
import os
path = 'path/to/directory'
listt = ['/data0/river_routes.nc',
         '/dat/rho0_profile.nc',...]
all = set(listt)
found = set(os.listdir(path))
missing = list(all - found)
```